Reformulate a system of ODEs into an ODE on some norm
I had a complicate system of ODEs which I don't expect to obtain an explicit solution, while the ODE on their sum seems to be promising to have an explicit solution.
$$\frac{d\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}+0.5 [x_1(t),\cdots,x_n(t)]A [1,1,\cdots,1]^T=0,$$
where $A$ is an $n\times n$ constant matrix satisfying $A^T=-A$. Let $S(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(t)$, is it possible to obtain an explicit solution on $S(t)$ in terms of $S(0),A$ and $t$? Thanks.

Not in general. For $S$ to be solved directly using only $S$ requires that the system in $S$ be autonomous assuming you do not wish to solve for other states. For your equation this is only the case if $\mathbf{1}$ is a right eigenvector of $A$ (or in the null space). Being skew-symmetric doesn't help a whole lot here, since it does not determine this requirement. In the case where $\mathbf{1}$ is not an eigenvector, $x^\top A\mathbf{1}$ depends on states other than $x^\top \mathbf{1}$ thus implying more information is required to solve for $S.$
Speaking in the general case of arbitrary $A$ and $\mathbf{1}$ being an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ (or nullspace with $\lambda = 0$) you'll be able to write,
$$\begin{aligned}
0 &= \frac{d}{dt}\left\{ \mathbf{1}^\top x \right\} + 0.5\, x^\top\, A\, \mathbf{1}\\
&= \frac{d}{dt}\left\{ \mathbf{1}^\top x \right\} + 0.5\, \lambda\, x^\top\, \mathbf{1}
\end{aligned}$$
Then define $S = \mathbf{1}^\top x$ as you have and find,
$$
\frac{dS}{dt} = -0.5\, \lambda\, S,
$$
for which the closed form solution is well-known.
If it is not an eigenvector, then the dynamics of $S$ depend on other states of $x$ whose evolution you have not described in its entirety. It may be the case that there exists some autonomous subsystem containing the evolution of $S$ and some other states $x_i$ to aid in your analysis, but that would require quite a bit more advanced tooling if you are working with nonlinear systems.

Thanks for your response which make the question more clear. Could you please point the theorem on the comment ``For $S$ to be solved directly using only $S$ requires that the system in $S$ be autonomous". In addition, do you mean "other states" by solution including information other than $S$ itself, like $x_i(t)$ for example.

@Silentmovie, The claim can be arrived at via Frobenius's Theorem. The differential form $\omega = dS - \dot{S},dt$ describing the ODE can be integrated by an integrating factor if it is differentially closed, i.e. $d\omega \wedge \omega = 0.$ This amounts to finding a way to rewrite $\dot{S}$ entirely in terms of $S$ and $t$ (my bad in using the term autonomous. I mean independent of other states but time is okay). And yes, I mean information that is differentially independent to $\mathbf{1}^\top x$ (such as some $x_i$).
